# Is there a way for my roman numerals not to separate but it creates a line break? (SOLVED)

Tags: c

So I have a homework wherein I have to convert integer numbers to roman numerals. The code I use is this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    
    int N, i, a, num;
    
    (1<=N<=3000);
    
    scanf("%d", &N);
    for(i=0; i<N; i++){
        scanf("%d", &num);
        
        while (num != 0){
            if (num>=1000){
                printf("M\n");
                num -= 1000;
            }
            else if (num>=900){
                printf("CM\n");
                num -= 900;
            }
            else if (num>=500){
                printf("D\n");
                num -= 500;
            }
            else if (num>=400){
                printf("CD\n");
                num -= 400;
            }
            else if (num>=100){
                printf("C\n");
                num -= 100;
            }
            else if (num>=90){
                printf("XC\n");
                num -= 90;
            }
            else if (num>=50){
                printf("L\n");
                num -= 50;
            }
            else if (num>=40){
                printf("XL\n");
                num -= 40;
            }
            else if (num>=10){
                printf ("X\n");
                num -= 10;
            }
            else if (num>=9){
                printf ("IX\n");
                num -= 9;
            }
            else if (num>=5){
                printf ("V\n");
                num -= 5;
            }
            else if (num>=4){
                printf ("IV\n");
                num -= 4;
            }
            else if (num>=1){
                printf ("I\n");
                num -= 1;
            }
        }
        **printf("\n");**
    }
    return 0;
}
```

but the result of the code would be this:
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xUVo5.png)

I know I can remove the \n so it fixes the spacing, but we are required for the input to be in a new line, so if I remove the \n, the number I'll input will be next to the roman numeral instead of below it. For example, like this: [result without \n](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WgZgS.png)

What I want it to do is for the roman numerals to be in one line, but I can't for the life of me find a way to do it.

**solved: added "printf(\n)" after the while loop**

Comment: '(1<=N<=3000);' What do you want to do with that?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to remove that.

Answer (score 2):

You can remove the `\n` in all of the `printf`,  and then add a single `printf("\n")` after the `while` loop.

Comment: Even if I just add a single "printf("\n)" after the while loop, it is still the same result as the first picture.

Comment: Hello, I am stupid. I placed the "printf("\n)" in the while loop curly brackets. Yes. This does work as shown in the code by CGi03. Thank you guys for the help, I appreciate it <3.

Answer (score 1):

Of course if it works:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int N, i, num;

    scanf("%d", &N);

    for(i=0; i<N; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &num);

        while (num != 0)
        {
            if (num>=1000)
            {
                printf("M");
                num -= 1000;
            }
            else if (num>=900)
            {
                printf("CM");
                num -= 900;
            }
            else if (num>=500)
            {
                printf("D");
                num -= 500;
            }
            else if (num>=400)
            {
                printf("CD");
                num -= 400;
            }
            else if (num>=100)
            {
                printf("C");
                num -= 100;
            }
            else if (num>=90)
            {
                printf("XC");
                num -= 90;
            }
            else if (num>=50)
            {
                printf("L");
                num -= 50;
            }
            else if (num>=40)
            {
                printf("XL");
                num -= 40;
            }
            else if (num>=10)
            {
                printf ("X");
                num -= 10;
            }
            else if (num>=9)
            {
                printf ("IX");
                num -= 9;
            }
            else if (num>=5)
            {
                printf ("V\n");
                num -= 5;
            }
            else if (num>=4)
            {
                printf ("IV");
                num -= 4;
            }
            else if (num>=1)
            {
                printf ("I");
                num -= 1;
            }
        }
        printf ("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: OMG. Thank you so much!!! I can't believe the solution was just that simple. I love coding ;-;.

Answer (score 0):

From an OP comment: `I love coding`.

Great. But coding isn't copy/paste. Strive to get beyond the basics:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    struct { int v; char *s; } rnc[] = {
        { 1000, "M"  },
        {  900, "CM" },
        {  500, "D"  },
        {  400, "CD" },
        {  100, "C"  },
        {   90, "XC" },
        {   50, "L"  },
        {   40, "XL" },
        {   10, "X"  },
        {    9, "IX" },
        {    5, "V"  },
        {    4, "IV" },
        {    1, "I"  },
    };
    int nums[] = { 1492, 1950, 1997, 1998, 1999, 2022, 0, };

    for( int i, n = 0, num; (num = nums[n]) != 0; n++ ) {
        printf( "%4d - ", num );
        char str[ 32 ] = { 0 };
        for( ; num > 0; num -= rnc[i].v ) {
            for( i = 0; num < rnc[i].v; i++ )
                ;
            strcat( str, rnc[i].s );
        }
        puts( str );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

```
1492 - MCDXCII
1950 - MCML
1997 - MCMXCVII
1998 - MCMXCVIII
1999 - MCMXCIX
2022 - MMXXII
```

---

**EDIT:**
For the sheer *joy of coding*...
Each operation is as lean as I can make it.
For personal use; testing negative and other off-the-wall values is left as an exercise for the reader.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    // Roman numeral conversion array and a pointer
    struct { int v; char *s; } rnc[] = {
        { 1000, "M"  }, {  900, "CM" }, {  500, "D"  }, {  400, "CD" },
        {  100, "C"  }, {   90, "XC" }, {   50, "L"  }, {   40, "XL" },
        {   10, "X"  }, {    9, "IX" }, {    5, "V"  }, {    4, "IV" },
        {    1, "I"  },
    }, *p;

    // test values
    int nums[] = { 30, 444, 502, 1492, 1900, 1933, 1944, 1994, 1997, 1999, 2023, 0, };

    // use each test value one-by-one until 0 encountered
    for( int numIn, numOut, n = 0; (numIn = nums[n]) != 0; n++ ) {
        // slide along rnc list, reducing value and concatenating strings
        char str[ 32 ] = { 0 }, *ps;
        for( p = rnc; numIn; numIn -= p->v, strcat( str, p->s ) )
            while( numIn < p->v ) p++; // scan to appropriate value

        // reverse the process, looking up segments & accumulating value
        for( p = rnc, ps = str, numOut = 0; *ps; )
            if( ( p->s[0] == ps[0] ) && ( p->s[1] == '\0' || p->s[1] == ps[1] ) )
                numOut += p->v, ps += 1 + (p->s[1] != '\0');
            else
                p++; // scan to appropriate value

        printf( "%4d - %s - %4d\n", nums[n], str, numOut );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

```
  30 - XXX -   30
 444 - CDXLIV -  444
 502 - DII -  502
1492 - MCDXCII - 1492
1900 - MCM - 1900
1933 - MCMXXXIII - 1933
1944 - MCMXLIV - 1944
1994 - MCMXCIV - 1994
1997 - MCMXCVII - 1997
1999 - MCMXCIX - 1999
2023 - MMXXIII - 2023
```

Comment: Suggestion: if on each outer loop you check that the remainder is less than the `v` member of the selected entry in the table, your next inner loop can _start_ at the next entry in the lookup. E.g. `1105` is `"MCV"`. On the second outer loop, the M entry in the lookup table doesn't need to be considered. Similarly on the second outer loop we don't have to iterate over M, CM, D, CD, or C entries in the table.

Comment: @Chris Yes, I noticed the wasteful "resetting to zero" when I used the same table to reverse the process, turning Roman numerals into numbers... I'll post the revised code, with the reversal after the coffee kicks in... Cheers. (PS: Thx for "mmain" correction... I've got a setup that has a collection of "code modules" callable from an overarching "main()"... Too often I forget to 'fix' that... Thx... :-)